# What happens under the hood with `deriving` in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am just beginning to learn Haskell. I have seen many intro examples explaining the basics of types, but they often have a `deriving` statement below the type. Here is an example from [Chapter 3 of RealWorldHaskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/defining-types-streamlining-functions.html):

```
data Cartesian2D = Cartesian2D Double Double
                   deriving (Eq, Show)

data Polar2D = Polar2D Double Double
               deriving (Eq, Show)
```

They explain deriving somewhat in [Chapter 6](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html#typeclasses.wellknown.show), which helps you know how it is used.

So far from what I understand, `deriving (Show)` is necessary to tell Haskell how to turn your type into a string. That makes sense at a practical level. I come from JavaScript land, so to me you could easily imagine this would be implemented like:

```
Polar2D.prototype.toString = function(){
  return '[Polar2D]';
};
```

In Haskell, they give the example of how to implement your own `Show` for the `Color` type, instead of using `deriving`.

```
data Color = Red | Green | Blue
instance Show Color where
  Red = "red"
  Green = "green"
  Blue = "blue"
```

That means when your in the `ghci` repl, you can do:

```
> show Red
"red"
```

But this doesn't explain what `deriving` is actually doing, it's still magic to me.

My question is, what is happening under the hood with `deriving`? Also, is there a place on GitHub in the Haskell source where you can see the implementation? That may also be helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

GHC is effectively just writing the same instance you wrote by hand, if you pass `-ddump-deriv` to the compiler you can see the code it generates. For instance:

```
Prelude> data Color = Red | Green | Blue deriving (Show)

==================== Derived instances ====================
Derived instances:
  instance Show Color where
    showsPrec _ Red = showString "Red"
    showsPrec _ Green = showString "Green"
    showsPrec _ Blue = showString "Blue"
    showList = showList__ (showsPrec 0)


Generic representation:

  Generated datatypes for meta-information:

  Representation types:
```

There's not really much magic going on here, `Show` just has a very mechanical implementation. Inside it looks at the internal form of the data constructors (the type is `DataConRep` in GHC's source ) which it gets from translating the frontend AST and then looks at the names provided in the frontend source and adds a new Show instance in terms of these names and any nested types that also implement Show. The new auto-generated typeclass is registered just like a hand-coded class as if it were written in the current module.

Comment: that's true here, but some weird stuff can happen (though I'm no expert on GHC). like [1] with `GeneralizedNewTypeDeriving`, it generates no instances, but safely reuses the inner types' instances. also [2] with `DeriveDataTypeable`, you can't write a manual `Typeable` instance.